# Hit area of button inside of a grid is messed up

Tags: swiftui

This is weirding me out. I have a few buttons in a grid. However, no matter where I tap in the grid, one button always gets hit. Once I disabled that button, another button always gets the hit.

If I change the grid to a section, everything works fine. I have added a border to the buttons to visualize their sizes, and everything looked fine.

[image: buttons in grid]

Here's my code:

```
Grid {
  GridRow {
    Button(action: pick) {
      Label("Pick", systemImage: "doc.fill.badge.plus")
    }
    .border(Color.black)
    
    Spacer()
    
    Button(action: upload) {
      Label("Upload", systemImage: "arrow.up.circle.fill")
    }
    .border(Color.black)
    .disabled(model.outgoingFiles.isEmpty || model.outgoingFiles.allSatisfy({$0.isUploaded || $0.isUploading}))
    
    Spacer()
    
    Button(action: send) {
      Label("Send", systemImage: "arrow.up.backward.circle.fill")
    }
    .border(Color.black)
    .disabled(model.outgoingFiles.isEmpty || !model.outgoingFiles.allSatisfy({$0.isUploaded}))
  }
}

ForEach(model.outgoingFiles) {file in
...
```

Initially, it's always the "Upload" button that gets hit. Then my code triggers changes to the `disabled` logic and disables "Upload" and enables "Send". Then it's always "Send" that gets hit.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Grid` is not the issue.

The issue is because of the `List`. You should set the button style to something **other than** the `.automatic` like this:

```
.buttonStyle(.plain)
```

You can apply it to all buttons at once like:

```
List {
   ,,,
}
.buttonStyle(.borderless)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. For the life of me, I can't understand the behaviour when it's set to `.automatic`. Why would anyone want a behaviour like that?!